# ataX: softreset failed

Tags: boot, drivers, hard-drive, mate, sata

My system is Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS. I have a problem with:

[    2.037058] ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)

[    2.037080] ata1: softreset failed (device not ready)

[    2.225055] ata3: softreset failed (device not ready)

I use 3 hard disc including one SSD.

My computer components (quite old):
AMD Phenom X4 9750

Gigabyte GA-MA770-UD3

Ram 7GB

SSD Micron 1100

2 x Hard Disc

Nvidia GeForce 9800GT Zalman

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Analyzing the model names in your question gives a clue about aging of hardware. Including maybe HDD. You have to check their SMART from GNOME Disks and/or GSsmartControl or on low level by MHDD, Victoria or something similar. Motherboard may be faulty too, or SATA cables.

Comment: I was testing on a connected only SSD. There's the same problem. The HDD I disconnected the SATA cable and the power supply.

I'm also sending a Smart Test SSD
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zdc4rq9gkdbxsuo/scan_SSD.png?dl=0